# Closures and Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Is there any functional difference between these to function calls.

Method1:

```
public static void PrintMe(object obj)
{
    Task task = new Task(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
    });
    task.Start();
}
```

Method2:

```
public static void PrintMe(object obj)
{
    Task task = new Task((object arg) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg.ToString());
    }, obj);
    task.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first one passes the **variable obj** to the task. The second one passes the **value of obj**.

To see the difference assign something else to obj after creating the task.

```
public static void PrintMe(object obj)
{
    Task task = new Task(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
    });
    obj = "Surprise";        
    task.Start();
}
```