# Creating X amount of threads that execute a task at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am trying to dynamically create X amount of threads(specified by user) then basically have all of them execute some code at the exact same time in intervals of 1 second.

The issue I am having is that the task I am trying to complete relies on a loop to determine if the current IP is equal to the last. (It scans hosts) So since I have this loop inside, it is going off and then the other threads are not getting created, and not executing the code. I would like them to all go off at the same time, wait 1 second(using a timer or something else that doesnt lock the thread since the code it is executing has a timeout it waits for.) Can anyone help me out? Here is my current code:

```
            int threads = Convert.ToInt32(txtThreads.Text);
            List<Thread> workerThreads = new List<Thread>();
            string from = txtStart.Text, to = txtEnd.Text;
            uint current = from.ToUInt(), last = to.ToUInt();

            ulong total = last - current;

            for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    for (int t = 0; t < Convert.ToInt32(total); t += i)
                    {
                        while (current <= last)
                        {
                            current = Convert.ToUInt32(current + t);
                            var ip = current.ToIPAddress();
                            doSomething(ip);
                        }
                    }
                });
                workerThreads.Add(thread);
                thread.Start();
            }
```

Comment: can you remove your `thread.Start` and after the for loop, do `workerThreads.ForEach(t => t.Start());`

Comment: It seems that you want to do network things. That means there are big latencies. So most of the threads are just waiting. You should consider an event loop like in node.js and use something with async and await. See here [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/481080/Continuous-asynchronous-Ping-using-TAP-and-IProgre].
If you still want to use threads you should also call Join on each thread.

Comment: @schoetbi I have actually created an Async implementation with the task parallel library. I am creating this so I can do some bench marks. I am mainly looking for speed along with accuracy so I want to see which implementation will be quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a lambda as the body of your thread, otherwise the `i` value isn't doing what you think it's doing. Instead pass the value into a method.

As for starting all of the threads at the same time do something like the following:

```
private object syncObj = new object();

void ThreadBody(object boxed)
{
    Params params = (Params)boxed;

    lock (syncObj)
    {
        Monitor.Wait(syncObj);
    }

    // do work here
}

struct Params
{
    // passed values here
}

void InitializeThreads()
{
    int threads = Convert.ToInt32(txtThreads.Text);
    List<Thread> workerThreads = new List<Thread>();
    string from = txtStart.Text, to = txtEnd.Text;
    uint current = from.ToUInt(), last = to.ToUInt();

    ulong total = last - current;

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.ThreadBody, new Params { /* initialize values here */ }));
        workerThreads.Add(thread);
        thread.Start();
    }

    lock(syncObj)
    {
        Monitor.PulseAll(syncObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I am trying this right now, we will see see how it goes.

Comment: I should add for anyone else, I actually could not use the parameterizedthreadstart, and had to use: Thread thread = new Thread(() => DoWork(paramobj)); or Thread thread = new Thread(() => DoWork(param1, param2, param3)); but this answer still worked, other than the slight change.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into closure problems.  There's another question that somewhat addresses this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392283/closures-and-tasks).

Basically you need to capture the value of `i` as you create each task.  What's happening is by the time the task gets around to actually running, the value of `i` across all your tasks is the same -- the value at the end of the loop.